# How to create a .app from output files of pyinstaller?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyinstaller

I have used pyinstaller to create an executable from python scripts on os_x. It creates a dist folder with the executable and its dependencies etc. Some of the files are shown in the image below:

[image]

Is there any way to create a single application bundle from these files? If so, how should I proceed?

Also, in addition to the GUI, the console pops up. How can I disable this pop-up?

Answer (score 2):

The following is the command line I use to compile a stand alone exe (self contained, without directory of shared components).  The important parameter is --onefile.   The --onedir parameter will produce the directory of exe with shared components.

To disable the popup console at runtime ... use the --noconsole parameter in your build command line.

c:\python27\python.exe c:\pyinstaller\pyinstaller.py --noconsole --onefile --workpath="C:\Users\alan\Documents\python" "C:\Users\alan\Documents\python\piechart.py"

Comment: I use '--onefile --windowed'.  The documentation is not clear whether '--noconsole' is the same as or in addition to '--windowed'